# Create number of table entries in new table from value in current table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm curious as to if there is a method for using a value in a table to create that number of entries in a second table. For instance in the first table you have entries of parts assemblies and each one has a certain number of bolt holes associated. In a new table the unit and assembly name should be passed to each hole associated, so that a user may fill in other attributes for each hole. So if there are 5 holes in the first table, it should create 5 rows with bolt numbers 1-5. Thanks!

Comment: yes this is possible. (sorry for terse answer but not much more to go on. Have you tried doing anything yet? )

Answer (score 0):

Not much to work with, but here are the basics:

```
Public Sub CreateRandomRecords(ByVal lngRecords As Long)

    Dim wks     As DAO.Workspace
    Dim dbs     As DAO.Database
    Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset

    Dim lngLoop As Long

    Set wks = DBEngine(0)
    Set dbs = wks.Databases(0)
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblRandom")

    wks.BeginTrans
    With rst
        While lngLoop < lngRecords
            .AddNew
            .Update
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                lngLoop = lngLoop + 1
            End If
        Wend
        .Close
    End With
    wks.CommitTrans

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Of course, if you work with a subform, it will be much faster and simpler to use the *RecordsetClone* of this as the recordset.